# Display information from a different layer in an attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have two different polygon layers we'll call them A and B. I would like to create an attribute table with fields that list areas of A and B (calculated using the $area function in field calculator). What is the best way of getting the two layers into one table so I can go on calculating overlap percentages etc.?

Comment: Please expand on your desired end-result, and detail your use-case. The optimal solution greatly depends on what you want to achieve, as well as on things like volume of data, or how much automation you need.